# tkinter scale slider value not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

below is my code for a basic tkinter scale:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('150x75')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

v1 = tk.IntVar()

ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient='horizontal', variable=v1).pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

below is the attached output :

[image]

why is the slider value not showing above the slider ?

I would very much appreciate if someone could point out the error with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in your code. I think the answer is "because it's not designed to". There is no mention in the documentation of the ttk scale widget that it shows the value.

Comment: but in every blog and video that I have seen the value shows and changes as the slider moves.

Comment: @ShidharthRouth the tk slider shows the value, but you're using the ttk slider.

Answer (score 2):

The tkinter.ttk version of Scale does not support showing the value.

But the tkinter version of Scale DOES support showing the Scale value, by default. The `showvalue` option defaults to 1. You can set it to `0` to hide the value if so desired.

Comment: Thanks. A lot of it. I've been fighting with tkk.Scale without knowing it. Your answer fix my issue. 3 lines and you fix an issue wich cost me 5 hours to find a solution. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Slider Demo')


root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)


# slider current value
current_value = tk.DoubleVar()


def get_current_value():
    return '{: .2f}'.format(current_value.get())


def slider_changed(event):
    value_label.configure(text=get_current_value())


# label for the slider
slider_label = ttk.Label(root, text='Slider:')

slider_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')

#  slider
slider = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient='horizontal', command=slider_changed, variable=current_value)

slider.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='we')

# current value label
current_value_label = ttk.Label(root, text='Current Value:')

current_value_label.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='n', ipadx=10, ipady=10)

# value label
value_label = ttk.Label(root,text=get_current_value())

value_label.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky='n')


root.mainloop()
```

Link to site from which I got the answer:- https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-slider/

Comment: thank you for replying, I was able to rectify my blunder and now it works how its supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You may try removing this `from tkinter ttk import *` if you have imported something like this at the top of your code. Simply importing this `from tkinter import *` helps in showing the values of the scale in slider.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

A simple like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('150x75')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

def sel():
   selection = f"Value = str{var.get()}"
   label.config(text = selection)

 
var = tk.DoubleVar()
scale = tk.Scale(root, variable=var )
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)


label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```